# How to update multiple rows by one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have this table:

```
// user
+----+----------+---------------------+-------------+
| id |   name   |       email         |  reputation |
+----+----------+---------------------+-------------+
| 1  | Jack     | jack12@google.com   | 10          |
| 2  | John     | J_1343@ymail.com    | 1423        |
| 3  | Ali      | 1992Ali@yahoo.com   | 322         |
| 4  | Peter    | p.54@gmail.com      | 950         |
+----+----------+---------------------+-------------+
```

Also I have two id number. `$op` and `$user`. I want to plus current reputation with `2` (for `$op`) and `15` (for `$user`). So this is expected output:

```
$op = 3;
$user = 1;

// user
+----+----------+---------------------+-------------+
| id |   name   |       email         |  reputation |
+----+----------+---------------------+-------------+
| 1  | Jack     | jack12@google.com   | 25          |
| 2  | John     | J_1343@ymail.com    | 1423        |
| 3  | Ali      | 1992Ali@yahoo.com   | 324         |
| 4  | Peter    | p.54@gmail.com      | 950         |
+----+----------+---------------------+-------------+
```

How can I do that by one query?

---

I can do that by two separated queries:

```
UPDATE user SET reputation = reputation + 2 WHERE id = :op
UPDATE user SET reputation = reputation + 15 WHERE id = :user
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not try:

```
UPDATE user SET reputation = reputation + (CASE id WHEN :op THEN 2 WHEN :user THEN 15 ELSE 0 END) WHERE user in (:user, :op)
```

Comment: It's better to add `WHERE user in (:user, :op)`, so update will not scan table and will not try to update all rows.

Comment: great idea Andrew. Added to example above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE user SET reputation = (CASE WHEN id = :op THEN reputation + 2 
                                  WHEN id = :user THEN reputation + 15
                                  END)
```

Comment: This will set everyone else's reputation to `NULL`.

Comment: `WHERE id in (:user, :op)`

Comment: @Barmar Do you think `ELSE 0` is needed in answer above?

Comment: @stack No, it's redundant because of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: yes the else is redundant but if for some reason you don't have the where clause it will stop it from modifying any other values.